# Ways to do Load Testing for Web Service Made for iPhone Application

Tags: .net, iphone, web-services, load-testing

It's something strange I am posting here, as I have little bit confusion since last few days..

I have made a web service in asp.net 3.5 using MSSQL 2005 as backend, for my iPhone Application.

Now, My Database have some critical fields like longitude and latitude, based on this almost all my web service is working.

Currently I have entered around 200 records to my db, and it's working fine in iPhone Device.

So, my question is what are the ways to test my web service for around 25,000 records, and what are the ways to fill some dummy data to critical fields like Longitude and Latitude ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Visual Studio test edition to create load tests for the web service.

A simple sql script should be able to fill dummy data for you. I am not sure about valid Longitude/Latitude values, but google should find you a list of values of places in the world that can be converted.

Comment: Any simple HTTP load testing tool will do - VS Test Edition is fine if you have a license, but I wouldn't go out and buy it. You can also check out Apache Bench (mentioned in another answer), Apache JMeter, or my own company offers free testing for up to 100 VUs  generated from the cloud (see http://browsermob.com). Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to a linux machine, you can use [Apache Bench](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html) which is a really simple load tester.  You can specify what url to hit with what frequency and what concurrency.

If you care about testing the performance, you should have a different machine generate the load.